# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 - How to convert this SQL request with QueryBuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a relation : **User -> [OneToMany] -> Profile <- [OneToMany] <- Group**

When a user joins a group, a profile is created with the couple user_id/group_id.

And I want to get the unjoined groups from a user.

This SQL request work good, but I want to translate it with QueryBuilder :

For the user with id 2,

```
SELECT g.id 
FROM Group g 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT group_id FROM Profile WHERE user_id = 2)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I think this should work

```
    $qb = $this->conn->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('g.id');
    $qb->from('Group', 'g');
    $qb->innerJoin('g', 'Profile', 'p', 'g.id != p.group_id');
    $qb->where('p.group_id = 2);
```

**edit
Sorry i didn't read the unjoined part.

Try this

```
$qb = $this->conn->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('g.id');
$qb->from('Group', 'g');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->notin(
       'g.id',
       $qb2->select('p.group_id')
           ->from('Profile', 'p')

           ->getDQL()
));
```

Comment: `$qb->select('g')  
->from('MyBundle:Group', 'g')  
->innerJoin('g.profiles', 'p', 'g != p.group')  
->where('p.user = 2')  
->getQuery()  
->getResult();  `
  
returns me joined Groups from User 2, I want unjoined Groups

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I was working on another stuff. I have made a few changes on my DB, now I have this request working [request](http://pastebin.com/tt3HJ5nU), but I wonder if there is a way to avoid the step between the two requests. My subrequest return me an array of array, but I want an array of ids...