# How convert SQL query to Doctrine2?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to convert this in Doctrine2.

Similar to these questions:
[Symfony2 / Doctrine2 - How to convert this SQL request with QueryBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023195/symfony2-doctrine2-how-to-convert-this-sql-request-with-querybuilder)
[How to convert a complex MySQL Query to Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793684/how-to-convert-a-complex-mysql-query-to-doctrine2)
[Convert SQL to Doctrine 2 Query Builder or DQL by using NOT IN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938497/convert-sql-to-doctrine-2-query-builder-or-dql-by-using-not-in)

Is it possible?

```sql
SELECT 
SUM(q.amount)

FROM(
 SELECT  amount
    FROM expense_report e0_
    WHERE
        (e0_.is_account_transfer = 0)
            AND (e0_.remove_date IS NULL)
    LIMIT 0, 2) q
```

Thanks

Comment: (via Help and Improvement Review Queue) - Improved title, added references to similar questions

Comment: Hi @user783029, what you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can archive your problem with this custom repository method:

```
public function getAmount()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("q");
    return
        $qb
            ->select("sum(q.amount)")
            ->where($qb->expr()->isNull('q.remove_date'))
            ->andWhere('q.is_account_transfer = 0')
            ->setFirstResult(0)
            ->setMaxResults(2)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

And simply use it, as example, in a controller method as:

```
public function testAction()
{
   ....
    $totalAmount = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:ExpenseReport")
                        ->getAmount();
    ...
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry @user783029 you are right, i haven't tested the principal thing... by the moment i haven't any new idea... if you have found or I/you will find a solution let me know!